# Sort list of lists by second element in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, list, arraylist, swiftui-list

I have something like this in swift:

```
var users = [[craig, 3], [bobbie, 6], [nygel, 3], [caroline, 8]]
```

and I want to sort the list by the 2nd element in the list (i.e. order should be: [[caroline, 8], [bobbie, 6], [craig, 3], [nygel, 3]]

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of data structure are you using here?

Comment: You are highly encouraged to use a custom struct for the model rather than a heterogeneous array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last`, casting and default values to sort

```
users.sort(by: { $0.last as? Int ?? Int.min > $1.last as? Int ?? Int.min })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
users.sort(by: {$0[1] as? Int ?? 0 > $1[1] as? Int ?? 0})

//[caroline, 8], [bobbie, 6], [craig, 3], [nygel, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use an Array mixing a String and an Int, maybe consider using a struct like in my example. 
Otherwise others already posted working solutions.

```swift
struct User{
    let name: String
    let prio: Int
    init(_ name:String, _ prio:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.prio = prio
    }
}

var users: [User] = [User("craig", 3), User("bobbie", 6), User("nygel", 3), User("caroline", 8)]

users.sort(by: {$0.prio > $1.prio})
```